Word add-in: How to navigate to image/range
I am working on an add-in that allows users to insert content from our service into their document. I am able to do this fine. I am able to get a list of all images inserted from our service, and display those images as a thumbnail in the taskpane.  Now, I want to be able to allow users to click on the thumbnail, and have word scroll that item into view.
To build my list, I am running the following code (it goes through all inlinePictures and looks at the altDescription to find items that start with a specific tag)
const base64Image = image.getBase64ImageSrc();
await context.sync();
image.track();
diagramList.push({ image, base64Image: base64Image.value, tag });

I then use the base64Image property from my list of object to display in the taskpane, and on click I am calling a method that takes the image that is being tracked, and call select as follows:
await Word.run(async (context) => {
      const image = diagram.image as Word.InlinePicture;
      await context.sync();
      const range = image.getRange();

      range.select();
    });

However, using .select() does not seem to be working. And by not working, I mean nothing happens.
I am thinking that this is probably to do with the fact that I am using objects across contexts (meaning, in separate Word.run statements).
Is there something I need to be doing to get the range correctly?

I was able to figure out the correct way to make this work.I needed to use the overload on Word.run to include the tracked object (to use its context), instead of the reference to same.
const image = diagram.image as Word.InlinePicture;

await Word.run(image, async (context) => {
    const range = image.getRange();
    range.load('no-props');
    range.select();
    await context.sync();
});

